# Macbook pro 13 2012 (HD4000) 8GB(1600 Mhz) single RAM stick issue

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, memory

I have a Apple Macbook Pro 13" 2012 IvyBridge HD4000 Model which came with
2GB x 2GB RAM.
I Recently bought a single stick of 8GB RAM 1600Mhz (which is compatible).
Gskill 8GB DDR3 FA-1600C11S-8GSQ Notebook Memory for Apple Mac
http://techshop.in/store/product_info.php?products_id=10064.

I removed both the old RAM DIMM's and placed the New 8GB RAM in upper slot and lower slot but when i boot the system after a few seconds or minutes the display gets 
distorted and system does not respond and have to hard boot.

Is it because i'm using only one stick?
Do i need to buy another same kind of 8GB stick to make it work...

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the RAM is just bad. It happens sometimes.

But try to rule this out. Reset [SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964) and [NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379)(why not?) and boot into [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) to check the memory.

Also you may try to use new 8GB stick paired with old working stick. If it will be OK than don't try to buy same second 8GB stick it will not work. Though it does mean you can use this module with different fully compatible one it's better to send it back.

Anyway I would recommend you are buying DDR3L. It's a new and improved standard your model of MBP supports.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, where you say you put the new RAM in the upper *and* lower slot.

Do you mean that you tried the new RAM chip in each slot, and in both cases it produced the same symptom?

Did you check, can your machine handle 8GB of RAM?

No, you don't need matching chips for RAM to work--or even a chip in both slots.

Have you tried resetting the P-RAM? How about the System Memory Manager? Apple Support online tells how to do that for each model.

Comment: Yes i meant tried with both slots and reproduced same issue. Mine is the Latest Ivy Bridge Macbook pro so sure it supports even 16GB with 1600MHZ speed..am not sure about having 2 sticks (can i use only one stick)..haven't tried resetting P-RAM...Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use only 1 stick, that shouldn't matter. Have you tried that stick (and that stick only) in both upper and lower slots, just to check that the slots are okay?